# Reflection issue: NoSuchMethodException <init> ...specification.SearchCriteria, [Ljava.lang.String;)

Tags: reflection, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, specification-pattern

Well, NoSuchMethodException is normally well self-explaining. Unfortunately, in my case, I couldn't even guess why I am getting such error.

I am taking care a code from other developer and I must maintain it. It was designed with specification pattern in mind. In order to make the search engine very generic, basically, any string passed from client to rest service is split in order to build the search criteria.

When executing  "clazzSpec.getDeclaredConstructor(SearchCriteria.class, String[].class).newInstance(param);" I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.com.mycompany.specification.SomethingSpecification.<init>(br.com.mycompany.specification.SearchCriteria, [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Looking the image bellow, I can't see what is missed

SearchCriteria:

```
public class SearchCriteria {

    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;

    public SearchCriteria(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

SomethingSpecification

```
public class SomethingSpecification extends Specification<Something> {

    public SomethingSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        super(criteria);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Something> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        switch (criteria.getOperation()) {
        case "=":
...
        }
        return super.toPredicate(root, query, builder);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection code looks for a constructor with two arguments: `SearchCriteria` and a `String[]`. But the only constructor for `SomethingSpecification` only has one argument.